# JQuery cannot load local picture by using append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, local

I'm facing a problem when trying to append local pictures by using JQuery.

HTML file;

```
<!-- a simple grid and an animate button -->
<div class="grid"></div>
<span class="animate">Animate</span>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/u/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/u/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

JQuery code:

```
//Creating 50 thumbnails inside .grid
//the images are stored on local. So we can use a loop to generate the HTML.
var images = "", count = 10;
for(var i = 1; i <= count; i++)
images += '<img src="/images/'+i+'.jpg" />';

//appending the images to .grid
$(".grid").append(images);
```

Well...I can see the picture is loaded in Dreamweaver, but it only shows me 10 broken picture icons in browser, seems the pictures are not loaded properly.
Can anyone help me with this? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have imported 2 external jQuery files. Use only 1.

```
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/u/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Also I think you have an additional forward slash just before images folder.

```
images += '<img src="images/'+i+'.jpg" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all
Follow these steps:

1)jquery-1.9.1.min.js ==> here `.min` is just minified version of `jquery`.

so,don't use both.use only one jquery version normal or minified.

your scripts would be like this:

```
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/u/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- jQuery easing plugin -->
<script src="http://thecodeplayer.com/u/js/jquery.easing.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

2) Make sure your Path for images is correct.

3)do you have imgaes whose names are numeric numbers.like 1.jpg

4)have your all images have .jpg extension.check it might be .png or any other.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the error:

```
images += '<img src="/images/'+i+'.jpg" />';
```

Using "/images/image.jpg" tells html to look for the root (begin forlder) of the server. Which would be right if you had a folder like "C:/Images", considering you are not telling the webserver the root is somewhere else. Otherwise, try:

```
images += '<img src="images/'+i+'.jpg" />';
```

or

```
images += '<img src="C:/whatever/folder/you/use/images/'+i+'.jpg" />';
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.